# Calling method off of super constructor in Java, is it right?

Tags: java, class, methods, super

If I have a constructor with two arguments, can I call super like this?

```
super(a,b).method
```

For example:

```
public class Money (){
     int euro=0;
     int count=0;  

     public Money(int a,int b) {
        a=euro;   
        b=count;
     }

     public int getPay(){
       return 100;
     }
}

public class  Pay extends Money{
   super(a,b).getPay();

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It would have been faster to try it than write this question.

Comment: Do you use an IDE -like Eclipse, Netbeans, intelliJ, etc.-?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible and does not make any sense. If `getPay()` is the parent class' method, it will be available to the child and can be called as such `getPay()`  or like `super.getPay()` in case the child overridden the method.

Comment: He wants it to create a new object whose type is it's parent.

Comment: But constructor has two arguments

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can call

```
public class  Pay extends Money{

   public Pay(int a,int b){
     super(a,b);
    }

}
```

and later on do

```
new Pay(1,4).getPay();
```

Comment: No `void`, and don't forget parameter types.

Comment: Why not just `new Money(1, 4).getPay();` directly? It's not like the parent class is going to change at runtime!

Comment: @Cruncher:   Yes I think it's better.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard U are right, I was in hurry, `void` is gone and types ale magicly added ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Not exactly.**  However, it seems that you are trying to do two things:

- Use the super constructor (Money) to define the Pay constructor
- Call the super (Money) version of `getPay()` when you call this version of `getPay()`.

If so, then what you want to do is this:

```
public class Money (){
     int euro=0;
     int count=0;  

     public Money(int a,int b) {
        a=euro;   
        b=count;
     }

     public int getPay(){
       return 100;
     }
}

public class  Pay extends Money{
   public Pay(int a, int b) {
       super(a, b);
   }

   public int getPay() {
       //This is redundant, see note below
       return super.getPay();
   }

}
```

Note: `getPay()` calling `super.getPay()` is totally redundant at this point (because you're overriding super.getPay(), and if you didn't you'd have access to it anyway).  But what you can do now is modify the method (for example, `return super.getPay() + someVariable;`).